# How do I end this program without repeating a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
import random

def tryAgain(yesorno):
    yesOrNo = input(yesorno)
    if yesOrNo == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        print("Game over!")
    yesOrNo = input(yesorno)

def playOneGame(low, high):
    secret = random.randint(low,high)
    response = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100: "))
    tries = 1
    while response != secret:
        if response < secret:
            print("Guess higher")
        else:
            print("guess lower")
        response = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100: "))
        tries += 1
    print("That took you ",tries,"tries!")
    return tries

def main():
    playOneGame(1,100)
    tryAgain("Try again? y or n ")

main()
```

So this is my program and I've got everything working except one little part. When the it goes through the tryAgain function in the main() and I type 'n' instead to stop the program and end it, it prints "Try again? y or n " a second time and then i press anything and then it just ends. How do I make it so that my program just ends when I type in 'n'?

Comment: first of all, avoid calling `main` from `tryAgain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that in the `tryAgain` function you are actually requesting user input twice.

try with

```
import random

def tryAgain(yesorno):
    yesOrNo = input(yesorno)
    return yesOrNo.lower() == 'y'

def playOneGame(low, high):
    secret = random.randint(low,high)
    response = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100: "))
    tries = 1
    while response != secret:
        if response < secret:
            print("Guess higher")
        else:
            print("guess lower")
        response = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100: "))
        tries += 1
    print("That took you ",tries,"tries!")
    return tries

def main():
    while True:
        playOneGame(1,100)
        if not tryAgain("Try again? y or n "):
            break
    print("Game over!")

main()
```

it works, I have just tried, and it's good fun!

Comment: Thanks! But I haven't learned what "not" does. What does it mean? if tryAgain doesn't run it breaks the loop and ends?

Comment: `not` is a monadic boolean operator that negates the value of truth of its operand. When the function returns False, meaning the user intends to stop, the `not` turns it into a True, satisfying the predicate of the `if` statement and therefore breaking the `while` loop

Comment: in case my answer is helpful and solves your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.